# Netbeans xdebug nightmare

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans6.8

I know what you're thinking, ANOTHER netbeans xdebug post?

Well, I've tried everything I've seen in other posts, and nothing seems to work.  Here's my setup:

- OS: Ubuntu 9.10
- PHP: 5.2.1
- Netbeans: 6.8

The following is in my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

I've tried switching ports (I've tried 9001, 9002, and 9034 so far), using zend_extension_ts, adding additional xdebug parameters in the config file, but nothing seems to work: Netbeans still says it's **waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)**

If I look at my phpinfo, I do see a whole section on xdebug, and the parameters are correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your log files? See xdebug.remote_log setting

Comment: Did you compile PHP by yourself, using --enable-debug?

Comment: Ok, so I added an xdebug.remote_log, and something weird is happening.  I have a php script which uses xdebug_call_function to test xdebug.  When I access the script in general, nothing gets written to the log.  However, when I start the netbeans debugger and access the script while it's saying "waiting for connection" I DO see results displayed in the xdebug log.  Netbeans never connects though...  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: No, i did not compile php using --enable-debug.  This is the php i got when i did an apt-get install php5.

Comment: It looks like what's going has nothing to do with netbeans.  I cant connect to the xdebug port whatsoever, even with just php.  Has anyone had this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what happened, but I switched my debug port to 9000 and upgraded to Netbeans 6.9, and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

adding those lines solved my problems (usually)

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on

xdebug.profiler_enable = on

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on

xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p

xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

xdebug seems not working in "run as script" mode
try it on your local website